# PhoneGap toggleClass not working on android app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, toggleclass

I'm developing an Android App with PhoneGap, since I updated PhoneGap to latest version (2.2.0) I found that toggleClass is not working instead I keep the button pressed for 3-4 seconds.

Let me explain a bit. I have a hiddable menu (list) which the user can hide/unhide by clicking on the title.

I have this javascript code:

```
var expander = function() {
    var li = $(this).closest('ul').find('li');
    for(var i = 1; i < li.size(); i++) {
        li.eq(i).toggleClass('d-none');
    }
    RefreshScroll(110);
};
```

And this CSS:

```
.d-none{ display : none;}
```

This approach works perfectly on the web and on iOS (with PhoneGap as well).

Any tip?